# Ruby on Rails before_filter vs ruby's initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just a thought in my mind. what is the difference the following

**before_filter**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :foo
  def foo
    @mode = Model.new
  end
end
```

**ruby initialize**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def initialize
    foo
  end

  def foo
    @mode = Model.new
  end
end
```

1. Does ruby's initialize method work as expected in rails?
2. If yes, then can we use initialize in place a filter has to be applied to all actions in a controller?

Comment: you're monkey patching something you do not know, without respecting the api. Cross your fingers or use before_filter

Comment: I guess, as Rails caches classes in production, that further would be executed only once preserver restart (or until gc removes the object, but this is unlikely for application controller). Mind it's just my loose thought

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, you'll get a fresh ApplicationController for each request.

Comment: Ok, so I was wrong, never dug this deep into Rails code I must admit. @naomik can you point me in the right direction so I can improve my knowledge? :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For each request, you do get a fresh instance of `ApplicationController`, but the big no-no here is that you're attempting to override core behavior of `ActionController::Base#initialize` without calling the parent behavior.

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def initialize
    super # this calls ActionController::Base initialize
    init_foo
  end

  private

  def init_foo
    @foo = Foo.new
  end
end
```

This is not idiomatic Rails behavior though. They give you `before_filter` for a reason; so use it.

Comment: so callling function in initialize+super, is same as calling function with `before_filter`?

Comment: @GaurishSharma it's probably similar, but the order of things certainly matters. E.g., do you call `super` before `init_foo` or after? Unless you have a deep understanding of the way `ActionController::Base` is setup, there's little gotchas you could run into. `before_filter` gives you the behavior that's desired and it's the "Rails Way" of doing things. If you're using Rails, just go with the flow, otherwise you're likely to run into trouble.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this was covered in [Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321721330) by Sandi Metz.

Suppose you are designing a base class for other developers/users, and want to allow them to hook into various steps in a procedure (*e.g.* initialization.) In general, there are two ways:

1. Break up the procedure into small methods, and (in the documentation) remind users to use `super` whenever they override a method.
2. Include calls to various empty hook methods that users can override with custom functionality.

(I believe that these are variations of the [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern.)

The second way requires more effort on your part and less effort for your users.

In this specific case, `before_filter` provides a cleaner way to attach multiple hooks and encourages you to break up hooks into single-responsibility methods with meaningful names. This becomes more important in applications that use more controller inheritance.