# Rails: $ is not defined after initialize method definition

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, internationalization, initialization

I defined `initialize` method for my `ApplicationController` to set localization. It looks like that:

```
def initialize
  I18n.available_locales = [:pl,:en]
  I18n.locale = :pl
end
```

Unfortunately it causes error in my browser:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

There're problems with CSS too. How should I hook myself up to initialization process to avoid these strange problems?

**//edit**
Page works properly (with working JQuery) when I delete my `initialize` method declaration, so the problem is not with JQuery itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not define any initializers in your controllers. The proper way to set request context is via `before_action` callbacks.

```
class ApplicationController

  before_action :set_default_locale

  private

  def set_default_locale
    I18n.available_locales = [:pl,:en]
    I18n.locale = :pl
    # or whatever it is you need to do
  end
end
```

Comment: ok, thanks, it works :) could you maybe explain what exactly was happening in my strange case and why? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: @KarolSelak: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18576150/125816, for example. What you did, it disables half of rails :)

Comment: Generally speaking, if you override existing methods that a library (in this case Rails) relies on, don't forget to call `super`. Sergio's approach with callbacks is correct but you might also be able to get your solution running by simply adding a call to `super` to your `initialize` method.

Answer (score 0):

To fix issues with jQuery, try putting jQuery script tag on the end of the HTML head. For example:

```
<head>

    ...

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```