# access params inside initialize (constructor) of the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to change the value of keys inside params of a controller. I don't want to do it each method but do it at a constructor level. But when I access it inside initialize I get this error

"*NoMethodError (undefined method `parameters' for nil:NilClass):*"

```
 class MyController < ApplicationController

        def initialize
          puts params.inspect #params is nil!
        end
end
```

I also tried to do that using before_action but the same error

```
 class MyController < ApplicationController
      before_action :my_initializer
        def initialize
          puts params.inspect #params is nil!
        end

     def my_initializer 
       puts params.inspect #params is nil!
     end
  end
```

Thanks

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18576384/3784008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `before_action` without `initialize` to make it work:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :my_initializer

  def my_initializer 
    puts params.inspect
  end
end
```